# Gray line between views in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I've designed an interface in my storyboard with a `UISplitViewController`.

- The master view controller is a `UINavigationViewController` with a `UITableViewController` as root view controller. The navigation controller is set to show its navigation bar.
- The detail view controller is a `UIViewController`. Its view contains 2 elements : a navigation bar and a web view.

I set the background color of both navigation bar with :

```
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bckgrd_image.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

There is no issue with iOS6, but running on iOS7, a "gray line" between the two views of my split view controller.

[image]

What could this be due to?

**EDIT**

An answer has been deleted, but it does the trick :

```
// In my split view controller class
UIView *coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 1, 64)];
[coverView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.view addSubview:coverView];
```

So I've try to set the background color programmatically (impossible to do this from I.B.)of my split view controller and it works.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: Is you bckgrd_image shorter than the width of the nav bar?

Comment: Yes, it's a 1x44 png image that I want to use like a tile.

Comment: This could be the problem - try making an image that is (a little) longer than your nav bar.